# What does this code do?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public String postal {get; set {postal = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
```

please explain about this line

Answer (score 6):

This is composed of:

- The shortcut syntax for exposing a field via a getter and a setter method
- In a property set, the value being set is available in a variable named `value` - see [Apex Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm).
- ? : is the [ternary (conditional) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

So when a string is assigned to the postal field, if the string is not null it is trimmed (white space removed) but if it is null the null value is assigned. So this safely makes sure that the postal field contains a trimmed string or null.

Answer (score 2):

```
If (Value == null)
   return value;
Else
  return value.trim();
```